# Why does the below multi threaded code result in SIGABRT ?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

The below code i have blows up when run with switch flag that enables mutex protection. ie run as ./code.out 1

Now the stack trace of core dump points towards memory allocation issue perhaps happening from the fact that every insert from the thread results in a realloc of the whole vector due to size increasing beyond the reserved memory initially.

The trace is :

```
\#0  0x00007f1582ce6765 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
\#1  0x00007f1582ce836a in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
\#2  0x00007f1582d27710 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
\#3  0x00007f1582d2feaa in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
\#4  0x00007f1582d3340c in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
\#5  0x0000000000403348 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) ()
\#6  0x00000000004029b2 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate(std::allocator<int>&, int*, unsigned long) ()
\#7  0x00000000004020ae in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long) ()
\#8  0x0000000000401e4e in void std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<int const&>(int const&) ()
\#9  0x0000000000401707 in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::push_back(int const&) ()
\#10 0x0000000000401212 in pushItem(int const&) ()
\#11 0x0000000000403d88 in void std::_Bind_simple<void (*(unsigned int))(int const&)>::_M_invoke<0ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul>) ()
\#12 0x0000000000403cd3 in std::_Bind_simple<void (*(unsigned int))(int const&)>::operator()() ()
\#13 0x0000000000403c6e in std::thread::_State_impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*(unsigned int))(int const&)> >::_M_run() ()
\#14 0x00007f158364f5cf in ?? () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
\#15 0x00007f15839235ca in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
\#16 0x00007f1582db50ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

When i run the same program as with reserve(20) it works fine. the question is what is going on here. I assume with mutex protection also if this is happening then there is something i am missing that is inherently flawed 
with vector interface itself. Kindly guide !!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<mutex>
#include<thread>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

std::vector<int> g_vector;
std::mutex g_mutex;
bool demoFlag = false;

void pushItem(const int& ref)
{

    if(demoFlag)
    {
        cout << "Locking is enabled. so i am locking" << endl;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    }

    g_vector.push_back(ref);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if(argc == 2)
        demoFlag = atoi(argv[1]);

    g_vector.reserve(10);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        g_vector.push_back(i);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<10; ++i)
        threads.push_back(std::thread(pushItem,i));

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

    for(const auto& ref : g_vector)
        cout << "Item is = " << ref << " , ";
    cout << endl;


}
```

Comment: What do you think you're locking using that mutex?

Comment: You are having data races, which is undefined behaviour

Comment: Got it guys! :( my poor the if loop esentially unlocks after the end of it :(( stupid on me

Comment: It is solved now thx guys :( It was poor simple mistake sometimes things are way more simple than we are trying to imagine...

Comment: Don't use namespace std, consider emplace_back instead of push_back, the reference for the parameter to pushItem is unnecessary, and I think the reference ends up getting "ignored" anyway because it's an std::thread. And then the data race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lock is not be used. some code should be like this:

```
void pushItem(const int& ref)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    cout << "I am locking" << endl;

    g_vector.push_back(ref);
}
```